# node-gyp - Handling ".h.in" files

Tags: python, c++, node.js, autoconf, node-gyp

I created a project which contains a git submodule [`libxml2`](https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2). I want to use this files inside my `binding.gyp`, but i get errors while running `node-gyp build`. The problem here is that there is only a `xmlversion.h.in` file but an `xmlversion.h` file is needed.

When i am running the [`autogen.sh`](https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/blob/master/autogen.sh) script of `libxml2` first everything is working fine, because the `autotools` will create the `xmlversion.h` file out of the `xmlversion.h.in`.

Is there a way to create the `xmlversion.h` file using `node-gyp`?

My current `bindings.gyp` looks like that:

```py
{
    'targets': [{
        'target_name': 'library',
        'product_extension': 'node',
        'type': 'shared_library',
        'include_dirs': [
            'libxml2/include',
            'libxml2',
            "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")"
        ],
        'cflags': [ '-Wall' ],
        'xcode_settings': {
            'OTHER_CFLAGS': [ '-Wall' ]
        },
        'sources': [
            # src/my_files.cc
            # libxml2/libxml2_files.c
        ]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to use node-gyp and mix it with autotools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to solve the problem of `.h.in` in files is to build it once using the `autotools` and to copy the created `.h` files to an other directory of the project (So the submodule will not be affected). Furthermore, you may have to build these files for several platforms or architectures. After that you can add a new folder to your includes. A pretty nice solution for that is available here:

[Github DEMO](https://github.com/albanm/node-libxslt/tree/master/deps)